# How can all of a shell command be preserved when using variables in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
stage('build') {
      environment {
        WORKDIR="""${sh(
                returnStdout: true,
                script: 'pwd'
            )}"""
      }
      steps {
        timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
          sh "usermod -d ${WORKDIR} jenkins"
        }
      }
    }
```

The result of the above gives

> usermod -d /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/-www_feature_ci-integration-GWZMSYY6XHJA7QDBD4KWGXZCOVUKOBI35JMKYOQV76QXZTCYE6CA
>
> Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN

What happened to the user `jenkins` that I specified, it seems to have been trimmed away from the command. Is there a way to preserve it?

Comment: You probably have a trailing newline in your `${WORKDIR}` assignment. `.trim` it and then see if that works.

Comment: thanks, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking a `sh` method with `returnStdout: true`, often a newline will be returned with the output. If you are assigning this output to a variable, then the resulting string value will also contain a newline character. This means your `sh "usermod -d ${WORKDIR} jenkins"` will be `usermod -d /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/-www_feature_ci-integration-GWZMSYY6XHJA7QDBD4KWGXZCOVUKOBI35JMKYOQV76QXZTCYE6CA\n jenkins"`. The command will then execute without the `jenkins` user argument.

To fix this, you can make use of the `.trim()` method to remove the newline (and trailing whitespace).

This can most easily be done with either:

```
WORKDIR="""${sh(
             returnStdout: true,
             script: 'pwd'
           ).trim()}"""
```

during the assignment or:

```
sh "usermod -d ${WORKDIR.trim()} jenkins"
```

during the string interpolation.